# how to get event in error replacement in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Firefox and IE the event is not working,
My code is

```
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var relatedTargetId = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('id');  
        if(relatedTargetId && relatedTargetId.toLowerCase() == 'cancel') {
            $('#'+relatedTargetId).trigger('click');
            console.log('triggered click');
        }
    },
```

I am trying to get the id of related target but in Firefox I am getting event as undefined. And in IE also it is not working

Comment: In what browser IS it working?

Comment: FF isn't using global event model, you need to pass it explecitely to event handler. Now your posted code is missing some context to make your question more clear

Comment: chrome it is working fine and can you please tell me what more you required to understand the issue? i will add it

Comment: what does `element` contain? would `$(element).attr('id');` be the same as `$(event.relatedTarget).attr('id');` ? or `$(error.relatedTarget).attr('id');` instead?

Comment: Actuallyt i am doing validation on focusout, so when I first click on the cancel button instead clearing the form the validation is happening which not the correct one. So i am trying to get relatedTarget of event. Element is the input field which is focused. But here I want the cancelbutton id

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put the event as a parameter of the function?

Comment: no, can i pass it as the parameter in errorplacement function?